# In Excel 2013, how to force a date format when printing?

Tags: excel

[image]

I am setting a footer for printing, as shown in picture below.

How do I force the format to be DD MMM YYYY? For example,

```
13 Oct 2015
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following macro can accomplish this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UpdateFooter()

        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = Format(Now, "mmm d yyyy")

End Sub
```

You can use `LeftFooter` or `CenterFooter` in place of `RightFooter` if that makes sense in your workbook.

If you want to apply the footer update to all worksheets within a workbook, you can loop through them like so:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UpdateFooter()

        Dim ws As Worksheet

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                ws.PageSetup.RightFooter = Format(Now, "mmm d yyyy")
        Next ws

End Sub
```

A full list of members of the `PageSetup` object can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841253.aspx).